# not_iff_compat not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

I'm quite new to Coq, and I have an error when I try to use [`not_iff_compat` theorem](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Logic.html#not_iff_compat) in a proof. For instance, given the following mwe:

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Logic.
Lemma dummy: forall A B, (A <-> B) -> (~A <-> ~B).
Proof.
  apply not_iff_compat.
Qed.
```

Coq tells me: "`Error: The reference not_iff_compat was not found in the current environment.`"

(As far as I now, Coq.Init.Logic is automatically loaded so not necessary here, but the problem is the same without).

Remarks: I use CoqIde 8.6, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link starts with https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/, but the current version is 8.7.0 as of now and Coq v8.6 does not have the lemma in that module.
You can browse the standard libraries of different Coq versions by replacing 'current' with the version of your choice, e.g. like so: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.6.1/stdlib/Coq.Init.Logic.html.

Just a tip: usually you can append `#lemma` to the file path to get a more precise link: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Init.Logic.html#not_iff_compat.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't aware Coq 8.7 was out (not in my distrib repo yet). And thanks for the tip, I think I modified it while you were writing your answer :-)